# Can the performance of MacOS Extend Display between Macs be improved by cable connection?

Tags: macos, mac, display, performance

I have a M1 Mac Studio from which I "Extend Display" to a 16" M1 MacBook Pro, via the setting "Use As Separate Display". The connection happens over Wi-Fi, and the wireless router is situated very closeby. The performance on the MacBook Pro is not good: mouse cursor movements are choppy.

Can the performance be improved by a cable connection? E.g.:

- Connecting a USB-C or alternatively Thunderbolt cable between the two Macs?
- Connecting the MacBook Pro to Ethernet instead of Wi-Fi? The Mac Studio is wired via Ethernet to the wireless router.